# Javascript/Prototype adding two event handlers to a single field when I just want one

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm using prototype to attach event handlers to a number of form fields.  The form fields are named "ContactAddress", "ContactCity", "ContactState", "ContactZip" as well as another set that begins with "ContactProfile".  Now, the event needs to be able to tell the difference between when I'm updating a "Contact" field and a "ContactProfile" field so I have a data structure and code that works like this:

```
var geos = {
    'Contact' : [
        'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip'
    ],
    'ContactProfile' : [
        'Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip'
    ]
};
// Called on page load
function watchGeo() {
    for(prefix in geos) {
        geos[prefix].each(function(item) {
            $(prefix + item).observe('change', function() {ajaxgeolocate(prefix, item);});
        })
    }
}
// Doesn't actually geolocate anything yet, just tells me that the event works and what params got passed.
function ajaxgeolocate(prefix, suffix) {
    alert(prefix + " " + suffix);
}
```

Upon loading the page, when I change one of the ContactProfile fields, it gives me an alert box that says "ContactProfile Address" (for example) like it should.  However, if I change one of the Contact fields, it gives me an alert box that also says "ContactProfile Address".  Curious, I inspected the field and found out that two event handlers had been added to all Contact fields, instead of just one.  ContactProfile fields all have one event, as they should.

What's going on here?

Comment: No offense, and I appreciate the final answer, but you literally answered my question within a minute or two of my posting it, and at first glance it didn't seem to me that you had even comprehended the question in the first place.  After some more banging my head against the wall I finally unrolled the loop and didn't check back for a few days, so I didn't see your final response until now.

Still, I appreciate the fact that you took the extra effort to get a correct answer, and for that you'll get an accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens here:

```
function watchGeo() {
    for(prefix in geos) {
        geos[prefix].each(function(item) {
            //alert($(prefix + item))
            $(prefix + item).observe('change', function() {ajaxgeolocate(prefix, item);});
        })
    }
}
```

The variable 'prefix' is a member of 'watchGeo' and is included in the closure function passed to .each(). However when you get to the 2nd prefix, the first one is overwritten in all previous closures passed to .each().

Further more, it's even worse, 'prefix' becomes a global variable since you never declare it inside the function scope.

Try:

```
function appendGeoWatcher(prefix, item) {
    $(prefix + item).observe('change', function() {ajaxgeolocate(prefix, item);});
}

function watchGeo() {
    for(var prefix in geos) { // var prefix, keeps it local.
        geos[prefix].each(function(item) {
            appendGeoWatcher(prefix, item)
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If that were the case, why aren't there two event handlers on every field?

Comment: Updated, was fun finding it ;oP

Comment: Ah, this was quite insightful.  I had actually 'fixed' it a day or two ago by unrolling the loop and doing eight separate calls, but this was insightful.